# How does the value inside () in function work?

Tags: javascript

I've tried to decode the code I've been studying for a while. But, probably, because of my beginner mindset, so I still cannot understand how it works.

Here's my question. The word 'text' inside function addTodo('text').
Where does it come from? or it's declared as its own entity for itself. And what is it for?

Thank you in advance

```
 function addTodo(text) { // The 1st 'text'
    const todo = {
        text, // the 2nd 'text'
        checked: false,
        id: Date.now(),
    };

    todoItems.push(todo);
    renderTodo(todo);

}

const form = document.querySelector('.js-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const input = document.querySelector('.js-todo-input');

    const text = input.value.trim(); // the 3rd text
    if (text !== '') {
        addTodo(text);
        input.value = '';
        input.focus();
    }

});
```

Comment: Functions and how they work is part of every tutorial in the www that tries to teach JS...

Comment: "First" `text` = name of the argument, "second" `text` = property of an object, "third" `text` = variable in the event handler.

Comment: MDN has a [tutorial on functions](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

`function addTodo(text)` is the signature for the 'addTodo' function. It takes one argument, which is called `text`.

This argument is then used within the function. It's provided as the value of a property to an object called `todo` (this is a bit of a short-hand in JavaScript)

The 'third' use of text, is created as result of applying `trim` to the value property of the `input`. This `text` could have been called something else.

This use of `text` is then passed to the function we previously talked about, assuming it's not empty.

You could equally write the code as follows - it would work just the same

```
function addTodo(textForTheTodo) { // The 1st 'text'
    const todo = {
        text: textForTheTodo, // the 2nd 'text'
        checked: false,
        id: Date.now(),
    };

    todoItems.push(todo);
    renderTodo(todo);

}

const form = document.querySelector('.js-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const input = document.querySelector('.js-todo-input');

    const textFromTheInput = input.value.trim(); // the 3rd text
    if (textFromTheInput !== '') {
        addTodo(textFromTheInput);
        input.value = '';
        input.focus();
     }
});
```

Comment: So, you are saying that this (text) argument is used to tell the computer that it's the same as the text value inside the key named Text (text: textForTheTodo). Could you please explain why we need it. Thank you

Comment: @Chris410 [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. Since your answer didn't help me get through the question. Now, you're telling me to research more. I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: _"Now, you're telling me to research more"_ - Yes because all your questions so far can be answered with a beginner JS tutorial or with research here on SO or the www.

Comment: @Chris410 "why we need it" You need to give stuff names so that you can refer to them. Just like you have a username on StackOverflow that I'm referencing here.